# How to detect combo arrows with jquery?

Tags: jquery, arrow-keys

How to detect in jQuery comination of:

> Arrow Up + Arrow Right
>
> Arrow Up + Arrow Left
>
> Arrow Down + Arrow Right
>
> Arrow Down + Arrow Left

And not combination, just like

> Arrow Up
>
> Arrow Down
>
> Arrow Left
>
> Arrow Right

Comment: I guess it's no different from detecting any other combination of keys.

Answer (score 1):

I found much more easy dealing with key combos when using some plugin. I'm not a fan of using plugins for each thing, but sometinmes they just save a lot of time. My personal choice is

KeyboardJS - http://robertwhurst.github.com/KeyboardJS/